# Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: String

Tags: sobject, string, conditional

this is checkbox S1SD1__c

```
public static void moveStageBackward(Opportunity opp, Opportunity oldOpp, String newStage, String oldStage){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        System.Debug('-----Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>----------> '+objectFieldMap.keyset());

        for(Integer i=Integer.valueOf(oldStage); i >= Integer.valueOf(newStage); i-- ){
            for(String obj : objectFieldMap.keyset()){
                String stageName = 's'+i;
                if(obj.contains(stageName) && objectFieldMap.get(obj).getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.BOOLEAN || obj.S1SD1__c == false ){
                system.debug('-------getType----'+ objectFieldMap.get(obj).getDescribe().getType() + '--Boolean-- '+Schema.DisplayType.BOOLEAN);
                    opp.put(obj,false);
                    if(stageName == 's1'){
                      opp.ApproveStatus__c = ' ';
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like:

```
if(obj.contains(stageName) &&
   objectFieldMap.get(obj).getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.BOOLEAN || 
   obj.S1SD1__c == false ){ // Error here
```

That part should be:

```
   opp.S1SD1__c == false) {
```

Obj is a "string", which means it's not a record. The compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what to do.